# Create a toolbar like font size toolbar in ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to create a custom toolbar in ms word like the font size toolbar (See the screenshot) which is contain the line spacing value.

[image]

I know that the line spacing value return with this command. `Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing`

But I can’t understand that how to do this? I have searched on internet but nothing found.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use the default one?

Comment: Actually I want see the current line space from the toolbar. It’s really boring to see it from `Format->Paragraph` again and again.

Comment: You can simply edit your menu to include the desired command.

Comment: Please see this screenshot (http://prntscr.com/ktwcgf), there are no line spacing box like the font size.

Comment: I assume you mean a Ribbon control (toolbars haven't been in Word since version 2007, when menues and toolbars were replaced by the Ribbon)? If you really mean a toolbar, which version of Word is this? And you want a list of values such as 1, 1.5, 2, etc?

Comment: I am using word 2003. Please see this screenshot for more clearness--> https://prnt.sc/ktwsml. I want to show the `At` value in my toolbar.